# Adding information based on record in reverse order

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to ask some help. This is not homework but it is just an example on how I want to achieve so I provide example.

Here's my sample code.

```
$records = $stmt->prepare("SELECT fname, lname, birthday FROM names ORDER BY birthday DESC");

$records->execute()

foreach($records as $row) {
    $birthday = $row['birthday'];
    $fname = $row['fname'];
    $lname = $row['lname'];

<table>

<tr>
<td>
<?php echo $row['birthday'] . " | " . $row['fname'] . " | " . $row['lname']; ?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What I want to achieve is to have a student # before birthday in reverse order.

```
Student 4 | 1981-11-01 | John | Smith
Student 3 | 1980-11-01 | John | Smith
Student 2 | 1979-11-01 | John | Smith
Student 1 | 1978-11-01 | John | Smith
```

How can I do that? I have only loop through records and display it but I don't know how to add Student # in reverse order (old student below and new on top base on birthday)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should count the number of rows, print and decrement by one

```
$records->execute();
$num_rows = $records->num_rows;

foreach($records as $row) {
    $birthday = $row['birthday'];
    $fname = $row['fname'];
    $lname = $row['lname'];

<table>

<tr>
<td>
<?php echo $num_rows. "|" . $row['birthday'] . " | " . $row['fname'] . " | " . $row['lname']; 
$num_rows--;
?>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the database doesn't have student # field to store. so upon pulling the records from the database, i want to add student # in PHP but the student number will vary based on the record, old will be lower and student # start from 1. the latest is on top.